Dependencies overrides themselves in Kotlin Multiplatform project
I have Kotlin multiplatform project with jvm target.
It has two dependecies of LWJGL - sources and natives.
When I specify them together, I get only the source dependency. When I specify only natives, I get only natives. It looks like they conflicts with each other...
However, in a regular Java project they load without problems.
Has anyone encountered this problem?
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform") version "2.1.0-Beta1"
}

kotlin {
  sourceSets {
    jvmMain {
      dependencies {
        api("org.lwjgl:lwjgl:3.3.4")
        api("org.lwjgl:lwjgl:3.3.4:natives-windows")
      }
    }
  }
}

Source + natives

Only natives

Regular Java project


Does this impact on your code, rather than just IntelliJ ? Is there an example of a class that you can't access in a multiplatform setup?

@SimonJacobs
when specifying two dependencies, i can't access the resource file from the second dependency when running the application. This is not a problem of IntelliJ

I can't reproduce your issue.
If I run the following task from the multiplatform project with your build setup above:
tasks.register("dumpJvmDependencies") {
    doFirst {
        kotlin.targets["jvm"].compilations["main"].compileDependencyFiles.forEach {
            println(it.canonicalPath)
        }
    }
}

Then it shows that both jars are on the classpath.
Therefore I suspect that your problem is elsewhere.
If you are still having problems, I suggest you add some Kotlin code to your question which works as part of a JVM build but not as part of a multiplatform build. (Of course the Kotlin code to access these dependencies in a multiplatform project would need to be in the jvmMain source set.)
